# how can I get tableview label value on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new in swift and I want to get the value of label from tableview on button click

I am using code like this but it is getting crash

in cellforrowatindexpath

```
 cell.btnsubmit.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnsubmit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonSelected), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func buttonSelected(sender: UIButton){
        print(sender.tag)

         let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! PatientUpdateVCCell

         surgery_date = cell.surgeryDateTextField.text!
         discharge_date = cell.dischargeDateTextField.text!
         follow_up_duration = cell.lblfolowup.text!
         follow_up_date = cell.firstFollowUpTextField.text!
         patient_status = cell.patientStatusTextView.text!

    }
```

but it is getting crash. How can I achieve this

crash

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x11a794af0) to 'appname.PatientUpdateVCCell' (0x10ae74ae0).
```

Comment: please add the crash

Comment: add @IBaction for the button inside PatientUpdateVCCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your crash last superView is contentView then it's superView is the needed cell , so You need

```
let cell = sender.superview!.superview!.superview as! PatientUpdateVCCell
```

Answer (score 1):

Target/action is pretty *objective-c-ish*. And view hierarchy math is pretty cumbersome.

A *swiftier* way is a callback closure which is called in the cell and passes the cell.

In the cell add a callback property and an `IBAction`. Connect the action to the button

```
var callback : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

@IBAction func buttonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    callback?(self)
}
```

In `cellForRow` rather than the tag assign the closure

```
cell.callback = { currentCell in
     self.surgery_date = currentCell.surgeryDateTextField.text!
     self.discharge_date = currentCell.dischargeDateTextField.text!
     self.follow_up_duration = currentCell.lblfolowup.text!
     self.follow_up_date = currentCell.firstFollowUpTextField.text!
     self.patient_status = currentCell.patientStatusTextView.text!
}
```

And delete the action method in the controller